# Wildcard App ID for Developement Provisioning Profile/"No Code Signing Identity Found"

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, provisioning, signing

I am invited as a team member to a developer account. I need to send them a demo application via testflight. I checked inside the application ids list and there is no application created for this purpose. I am not able to create one either, since I only have "team member rights". What I can do though, is to download an IOS Team Provisioning Profile of Development type, that is created with the app id: Xcode IOS Wildcard App ID(*). 
All good and nice, but when I chose from X-Code the team that I am a member of, it tells me that "No Code Signing Identity Found". If I press Fix issue, I get the message "Your account already has a valid certificate" and that I can revoke and request a new one.

What should I do? Is the wildcard provisioning profile a viable option to create an archive?
What does it mean that I revoke my signing identity and request a new one? Does the developer account owner need to create a new certificate specifically for me? Or what is I don't understand about it? Is the signing identity related at all to the developer account? Or I will receive a new one automatically? Can anyone explain in a bit more detail, so that I understand properly?

Answer (score 3):

A wildcard simply means that it can apply to any app. If an app doesn't plan to use application specific requirements, like iCloud or inAppPurchases, then a wildcard profile is fine to use for the rest of your apps. In general, there is no need to download new profiles or certificates from develop.apple.com; you can manage them directly from xCode via Preferences>Accounts>View Detail.

Comment: Agree, a wildcard provisioning profile will only not block my bundle identifier to a single one. However, it seems that the "wildcard" concept doesn't have anything to do with my problem, but the fact that the certificate itself is not downloaded automatically due to having only member privileges.. In other words, I can see 0 signing identities in Accounts->View Detail, and I have no clue what would be the safest solution, so that I don't have to put the customer again through the long/painful process of creating a new provisioning profile with the newly approved requested certificate.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simpler then I thought, however it has created an unpleasant situation.
The thing was that XCode downloads automatically the code signing identity if you have agent/admin privileges. However, if you are only a team member and no admin/agent rights, you will not get a signing identity downloaded automatically, so you will need to ask the owner of the account to create a provisioning profile using the certificate that he needs to approve for you,( requested by you via xcode), or it should simply send you the certificate used to create the provisioning profile that you are going to use (this last one is not the preferred method).

Answer (score 0):

If you have been already invited, you only need to:

1. In Xcode, go to Preference>accounts
2. Select the company name in the bottom right - then click view Details
3. In the top screen (signing identities), click the + to get a new signing identity

You can confirm that has worked by going to the iOS member center and checking in the Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles. You will see your new certificate with your name.